# Как скопировать одинаковые папки со всем содержимым в мою папку

Tags: c#

Есть пути к папкам:

```
string allpaths = Path.GetDirectoryName(process.MainModule.FileName);
string mydirpath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrDir, "TestDir");
```

В каждом этом `allpaths` пути, внутри есть одинаковые имена папок: `Игроки`
Мне нужно скопировать эти папки с идентичным названием с добавление +1
Типо: `Игроки, Игроки1, Игроки2,` и.т.д чтобы был счётчик папок.
Всё содержимое файлов и папок внутри должны быть сохранены в каждую папку.
Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Вы практически готовый словесный алгоритм озвучили - осталось только записать его в коде, используя готовые языковые конструкции. Вот например, перечислить папки - [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories?view=netframework-4.8), далее открыли цикл for...each и начали каждую папку обрабатывать: создали новую, с добавлением плюс 1 на конце, скопировали файлы.... А вот чтобы прямо готового скрипта с добавлением единичек - представляете и нету у майкрософт готового.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С виду показалось, что это сложнее сделать, чем получилось в итоге

```cs
public string GetNextFreeFileName(string fileName)
{
    string candidate = fileName;
    int i = 1;
    while (Directory.Exists(candidate) || File.Exists(candidate))
        candidate = $"{fileName} ({i++})";
    return candidate;
}
```

Использование

```cs
GetNextFreeFileName(@"\Какой\То\Путь\Игроки");
```

Будет возвращать

```
\Какой\То\Путь\Игроки
\Какой\То\Путь\Игроки (1)
\Какой\То\Путь\Игроки (2)
\Какой\То\Путь\Игроки (3)
\Какой\То\Путь\Игроки (4)
...
```